# how to add data in a database to variable in C# for Login

Tags: c#, ms-access

I need to make a Login and want to create it connecting with Database.

```
        OleDbCommand cm;
        OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection();
        cn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\LakshanP\Documents\C Sharp work with database\adhideit.accdb";

        cm = new OleDbCommand("select usnam,paswd from signin where usnam = @a and paswd = @b", cn);

        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usnam", textBox1.Text.ToString());
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paswd", textBox2.Text.ToString());

        string un;
        string pw;

        cn.Open();
        OleDbDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();



        if (textBox1.Text == "usnam" & textBox2.Text == "paswd")
        {

            new Form1().Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalied Username or Password");
        }
```

Comment: What's exactly your question?

Comment: "I want to know how to take username and password from the database to, two variables." Because i can take username and password from the login form(main window, two text boxes) And then make If condition and check for whether the stored username and password and typed username and password are same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get data from your executed query than you will require to read data from data reader i.e. dr.Read(), than check if it has rows that means username and password are valid, else invalid.

OleDbCommand cm;
        OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection();
        cn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\LakshanP\Documents\C Sharp work with database\adhideit.accdb";

```
    cm = new OleDbCommand("select usnam,paswd from signin where usnam = @usnam and paswd = @paswd", cn);

    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usnam", textBox1.Text.ToString());
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paswd", textBox2.Text.ToString());

    string un;
    string pw;

    cn.Open();
    OleDbDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();



    if (dr.Read())
    {

        new Form1().Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalied Username or Password");
    }
```

Comment: "I want to know how to take username and password from the database to, two variables." Because i can take username and password from the login form(main window, two text boxes) And then make If condition and check for whether the stored username and password and typed username and password are same.

Comment: You don't need to take username and password from DB, in above code sample you are sending username and password to db, if it will match than will return data(that means login sucess), else you will not get row(else login fial).

Comment: if you think answer was helpful than please accept as answer!